# Горизонтальное расположение графиков

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, визуализация

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from sklearn import neighbors, datasets

n_neighbors = 15

# import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()

# we only take the first two features. We could avoid this ugly
# slicing by using a two-dim dataset
X = iris.data[:, :2]
y = iris.target

h = .02  # step size in the mesh

# Create color maps
cmap_light = ListedColormap(['orange', 'cyan', 'cornflowerblue'])
cmap_bold = ['darkorange', 'c', 'darkblue']

for weights in ['uniform', 'distance']:
    # we create an instance of Neighbours Classifier and fit the data.
    clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors, weights=weights)
    clf.fit(X, y)

    # Plot the decision boundary. For that, we will assign a color to each
    # point in the mesh [x_min, x_max]x[y_min, y_max].
    x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
    y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
                         np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
    Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

    # Put the result into a color plot
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
    plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z, cmap=cmap_light)

    # Plot also the training points
    sns.scatterplot(x=X[:, 0], y=X[:, 1], hue=iris.target_names[y],
                    palette=cmap_bold, alpha=1.0, edgecolor="black")
    plt.xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
    plt.ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())
    plt.title("3-Class classification (k = %i, weights = '%s')"
              % (n_neighbors, weights))
    plt.xlabel(iris.feature_names[0])
    plt.ylabel(iris.feature_names[1])

plt.show()
```

Имеется такой код, он выводит картинку классификации по датасету.
Как сделать так, чтобы графики располагались горизонтально, а не вертикально (как сейчас)? Т.е. нужна сетка 1 на 2, а не 2 на 1. Тут видимо нужен `subplot`, но я никак не могу понять куда его приткнуть. Все время что-то не то выводит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12,6))

for i, weights in enumerate(['uniform', 'distance']):
    # we create an instance of Neighbours Classifier and fit the data.
    clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors, weights=weights)
    clf.fit(X, y)

    # Plot the decision boundary. For that, we will assign a color to each
    # point in the mesh [x_min, x_max]x[y_min, y_max].
    x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
    y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
                         np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
    Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

    # Put the result into a color plot
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
    ax = axes[i]
    ax.contourf(xx, yy, Z, cmap=cmap_light)

    # Plot also the training points
    sns.scatterplot(x=X[:, 0], y=X[:, 1], hue=iris.target_names[y],
                    palette=cmap_bold, alpha=1.0, edgecolor="black", ax=ax)
    ax.set_xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
    ax.set_ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())
    ax.set_title(f"3-Class classification (k = {n_neighbors}, weights = [{weights}])")
    ax.set_xlabel(iris.feature_names[0])
    ax.set_ylabel(iris.feature_names[1])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]